# How to drive Philips Hue lighting with NFC tags

Tags: applications, nfc

Recently I came to use my NFC tags again.

Wondering how I can use my NFC tags to automatize chores like:

- Turn the light on at noon (Alexa/Philips Hue)
- Turn the light off at midnight

**In essence I intent to use NFC tags as replacement for conventional light switches!**

I could not find any way to do this using the standard apps (NFC Tools / Trigger). I am not bound to a specific app solution.

I tried to use text-to-speech to verbalize Alexa commands with NFC Tools, but this failed since it seems a synthetic voice is not recognized.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use nfc tags for this. NFC tags are useful when you want to activate something by physically touching the nfc tag. `at noon` and `at midnight` don't require any physical action from the user. I think you are better off using a service like IFTTT or Tasker or similar ( I have no experience with Trigger) to trigger the lights at a specific time.

Comment: You can use NFC tags instead of a light switch.

Comment: @miva2 yes I intent to use the NFC tags like conventional light switches. How could I do this? I need to drive as I said Alexa or Philips Hue.

Comment: I know it is possible but don't remember the details. I came here looking for the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what an NFC tag is.  The tag has an ID number.  All it signals to the phone is "You just identified this tag as me".  Some app has to be looking for that tag ID, and have code to do something when the phone sees it.

You can use one tag to turn the light on, and another to turn the light off - but you don't use a tag to "turn the light on at noon", you just develop an app (or find one in Play) to turn the particular device on at noon (and the same thing for turning it off at midnight).

Google Assistant might even work - tell it to turn the light on every day at noon and turn it off every day at midnight.